# Using bindings with BrazosUI buttons

Tags: ibm-bpm, brazos

I'm used to using boolean bindings with IBM buttons to track if a button is clicked. The button in Brazos UI can be bound to any variable type but doesn't make automatic updates to booleans. How do I use bindings with Brazos UI buttons to track which was last-clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binding of a button is really only useful in tables. The acceptance of ANY variable type for the binding of a button stems from the use of determining the index of a selected row or obtaining the entire row object:
If you bind and integer to the button in a table, the binding will update with the index of the row when the button is clicked.
If you bind a variable of the same (singular) type as the table's binding, then clicking the button will update the binding with that row's data.
Both of those are handy interactions with the table control but don't work for tracking which button is clicked when used elsewhere on a coach. For that, you want to utilize the 'Button Control ID' configuration option. The most direct method is to bind the same string variable to all of the buttons you need to track. When clicked, a button will update that shared variable to match its own control ID. You can then use that unique ID in various scripting checks to take button-specific actions.

See the BP3 Help Center article for greater detail about this, including some examples: https://support.bp-3.com/hc/en-us/articles/217985767-Using-Button-Binding-with-Brazos-UI